# Why does underflow with floating points happen at 2⁻¹²⁶?

Tags: c++, floating-point

When representing a float, why does the exponent face underflow when it hits 2<sup>−126</sup> if 8 bits can hold everything from −127 (incl.) to 128 (incl.)?

Comment: This may help: [https://h-schmidt.net/FloatConverter/](https://h-schmidt.net/FloatConverter/)

Comment: underflow is defined by size of exponent which is part of floating point. Also note that underflow is defined in IEEE 754 so other floating points standards do not have to have it.

Comment: You may be interested in [`std::fpclassify`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/fpclassify).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Exponents range from −126 to +127 because exponents of −127 (all 0s) and +128 (all 1s) are reserved for special numbers. [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-precision_floating-point_format#IEEE_754_standard:_binary32)

Comment: So this means that -127 is reserved for 0 and +128 is reserved for infinity?

Comment: C++ standard doesn't define that. [IEEE_754 does](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_754).

Comment: To describe the floating-point encoding properly, there is no exponent of −127 or +128. There is an exponent field in the encoding. When the bits in that field are all zeros, they indicate two things: The exponent is  −126, and the leading bit of the significand is zero. When the bits in that field are all ones, they indicate the “value” represented is an infinity (if the bits in the significand field are all zeros) or a NaN (otherwise). Otherwise, the exponent bits represent an exponent whose value is 127 less than the number represented by the field as a binary numeral.

Answer (score 0):

(considering positive values only, for simplicity...) It has more to do with the 23 bit fraction.  Normally, you have 24 (there is an assumed 1 bit, aka "1.fraction") bits of precision.  But once the exponent is -127 (it's encoded value is 0, since the exponent is the encoded value - 127), this assumed 1 bit is gone (aka "0.fraction").  So, for subnormals greater or equal to 1/2 x 2^-126, you have only 23 bits of precision.  For subnormals less than 1/2 x 2^-126 and greater or equal to 1/4 x 2^-126, you have only 22 bits of precision.  Etc.